# What happens when a non-member clicks on vote button?

Tags: discussion, voting, anonymous-user

When a non-user (or we, when we are not logged in) click(s) the upvote/downvote button on a question/answer, the following message is displayed:

> Sending feedback...

and then:

> Thanks for the feedback!

It also opens a box for logging in.

My questions are:

- To whom does it send the feedback? (Users with some specific reputation?)
- What data does the *feedback* contain? (vote, IP address or what other things?)
- What happens to that feedback? (Is the user awarded/punished?)

Comment: See [Who gets the “Was this post useful to you?” feedback?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125779/who-gets-the-was-this-post-useful-to-you-feedback) on MSE, specifically the newest answer as the earlier answers are a little dated

Comment: @psubsee2003 do you mean [this answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/247419/295517)?

Comment: @psubsee2003 That only answers the first question, i.e., _Whom does it send the feedback?_ But what about the other two?

Comment: AFAIK it is used at least partially to generate the rankings here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/greatest-hits

Comment: @hackerdarshi that why it wasn't left as an answer. But at the same time, it contains enough info that you can figure it out yourself by looking at the data dump

Comment: It's used to [award obscure hats](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/270789/winter-bash-2015-secret-hats/271127#271127).

Answer (score 3):

The feedback can be found in a few places:

- [SEDE](https://data.stackexchange.com/). A query can be run by anyone, even people without an account, but creating new queries requires SQL knowledge.

  - The PostFeedback table contains the following columns: Id, PostId, IsAnonymous, VoteTypeId, CreationDate.
  - See [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/283540/323179) for some queries I made for this.
- [10k Tools](https://stackoverflow.com/tools/post-feedback).

  - There are only two advantages that this has over SEDE and that is that it's easier to use for the limited views it provides and also that the information is more up-to-date. There are a lot of disadvantages though, such as not being as flexible/powerful (you can't, for example, find the data for a specific question).
- The feedback is also used in generating the [Greatest Hits page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/greatest-hits), [according to some formula](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/243113/323179), a page which is not linked anywhere in the UI.

Although the data is available, in my experience nobody does anything with it as it's just inconvenient to access.